# Incorrect Office 365 Date Modified Format when browsing for files

Tags: windows-7, office365

My user has their regional Date Format as Month Day Year, however, when browsing in Office 365 the Date Modified format shows in Day Month Year which is not desired.

[image: Excel Browsing Window]

[image: Regional Settings]

When the user browses files outside of Office 365 the date modified is in the same order as the regional settings which is what is desired.

[image: Windows Explorer Browsing]

What setting is required to ensure that the date modified, when browsing with Office 365, matches the user's regional settings?

Also, other users are experiencing the same issue and the date modified format is not consistent sometimes it is in Year Month Day sequence.

Comment: What version of windows is this? I don't think it is an Office 365 issue. 
I am on Windows 10 and I just change a load of windows 10 language settings and it changed the date format in Excel's browse files list.

Comment: Thanks, we are using Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if [this](https://as.exeter.ac.uk/media/level1/academicserviceswebsite/it/documents/How_to_correct_American_dates.pdf) can be helpful for you but try changing the settings of your office365 account.

Comment: I've used all the hints provided in your suggestions.  Office365 indicates it may take time for the changes to be visible. I am hopeful the issue will be resolved. .. I'll let you know.  Thanks!

Comment: It's a pleasure to help you. Yes, you need to wait that the microsoft server apply the change, it should take few hours. If you will resolve please mark the answer as accepted.